# stack function call problem

Tags: c, function

i have a function called `fun1()`, which is used for recursion. I am confused regarding the first call to this `fun(--n);`. What it will do and how will my stack pop my functions after each function finishes?

```
void fun(int n)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
        fun(--n);
        printf("%d",n);
        fun(--n);
    }
}
```

My main function is as below:

```
    int a;
    a=3;
    fun(a);
```

I want to know the order of execution and what my stack will contain before, during, and after the function call of the first `fun(--n)`.

Comment: Why don't you run it, and find out?

Comment: There is going to be a bunch or very little on the stack based on the optimization you specify for your compiler.  I would run this in a debugger, set a break point at `if(n>0)` and examine the stack.  Normally you will see things like `ebp` frames and arguments passed in.  However this is dependent on your architecture.

Comment: -- is the [prefix decrement operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy3d35h8(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Some of these are highly compiler specific, which compiler/environment are you using?

Comment: @teacher, have a look at my answer probably it will help get a better view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output will be 0, then 1, then 2, and then 0.

1. Initially called with 3
2. Greater than 0, it calls fun(--n), which makes it 2.
3. This continues until it reaches 0.
4. It continues to the printf(), and prints 0 to the console.

What you aren't seeing is the intermediate calls. This is the full output (before the n > 0 part):

```
Fun call before n > 0; n = 3
Fun call before n > 0; n = 2
Fun call before n > 0; n = 1
Fun call before n > 0; n = 0
0
Fun call before n > 0; n = -1
1
Fun call before n > 0; n = 0
2
Fun call before n > 0; n = 1
Fun call before n > 0; n = 0
0
Fun call before n > 0; n = -1
```

Comment: Question asks for details about what happens before, during and after the call to fun. I think that means a clear explanation of when exactly n is decremented.

Comment: @David: That's what my example shows (and why I showed the intermediate calls).

Comment: `Greater than 0, it calls fun(--n), which makes it 2` is rather imprecise. At what point does n become 2, before or after the call? You should make that clear.

Comment: @OP: Read here about prefix operators - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy3d35h8(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It would be better to write it directly into your answer.

Answer (score 7):

It will print `0120`

```
                                  (3->[2]->1)
                                       +   +
                                       |   |
                          +------------+   +-------+
                          |                        |
                         ({2}->[1]->0)           ({1}->[0]->-1)
                                +   +                        +
                                |   |                        |
                 +--------------+   +----+                   |
                 |                       |                   +
                 |                       |                  (X)
                 +                       +
                ({1}->[0]->-1)          (0->X)
                       +    +
                       |    |
          +------------+    |
          |                 |
          |                 |
          +                 +
         ({0}->X)          (X)
```

The above is a representation of the call tree. Read like this:  The first number in the `( )` , wrapped in `{ }` is the value which the function receives for one call, the next number following an arrow represents the value decreased by one and it is used to call again. The `[ ]` represents when returning it is printed. The last number in `( )` is the value which is used to the second call after the `printf` . An `(X)` represents that it is not able to get into the `if` block. At the end of each `( )` braces the function returns to the point where it originated from (follow the lines). Note the value gets printed after returning of the first call.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but it looks better if you put the plus signs over the number so the flow is understood better. Like, from 3->2->1, put the + sign over the 2 on the left (the one not in braces). I edited it. Feel free to roll back if you see fit.

Comment: note what i have written: "The first number in the `( )` is the value which the function receives for one call" , but the first function call happens *after* decrementing the value, therefore i think it is appropriate to make the arrows from the next value.

Comment: @phoxis: Ah, well in that case maybe you should put that in curly braces ({}) because you have three numbers with arrows in parens.

Comment: @Code Monkey: i have changed the arrows spawn from the `[ ]` bracketed values, because it will be a clear indication that at which moment with which value the function was called.

Answer (score 4):

Well, each time you predecremement, you will reduce the value of `n` by one. The function calls will descend all the way to the bottom before anything is printed, then one of the bottom-most printfs will be called, and so on. You might like to visualise the descending calls like this:

```
fun(5): *               P
fun(4):  *         P    
fun(3):   *    P         *    P
fun(2):    *  P   P *  P  *  P   P
fun(1):     *P  *P   *P    *P  *P
time -->->->
```

where P represents a print and * a new call (might well be some typos in there). If you weren't doing the decrementing a second time, you get a W-looking call graph, as it keeps going down and up again and down, but the second set of calls of each function is on 'cone' lower, so it looks squashed on the right. The stack is never more than 5 deep (if the first call was fun(5), say).

No idea if that visualisation helps, but I did my best with the ASCII.

Answer (score -2):

Should look something like this:

at start: fun(3)
first call: fun(2)
at end: fun(1)